# DotNetNuke - Page Publishing - Scheduled "Go Live", Scheduled Removal

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there a module or technique for DotNetNuke that allows you to design a page and have it automatically become viewable to the public at a certain date and time?

Also, is it possible to have the page become disabled at a certain date?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pages and modules have a **Start Date** and **End Date** settings to control the visibility interval. 
These are found in the Settings - Advanced Settings section.

[alt text http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/760/dnn20100321152557.png](http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/760/dnn20100321152557.png)

Comment: The question was "at a certain date and time". This is the date. Is it possible to also set the time?